# Having Issues with "Client" inside MessageEmbed

Tags: discord.js

Code:

```
    const specifyembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor("Auto-Partner", client.user.displayAvatarURL())
    .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
    .setDescription("**__Want to grow fast?__** \nWith this bot you can gain up to **3,000 Members** per week! \nThis bot will share your server in many active servers and to many active users! \nSimply add me to your server and use the command ``-partner {MESSAGE}``")
    .addFields([
        {
            name: '**__Bot Invite Link:__**',
            value: '[- Click To Add Bot -](your link goes here)'
        }
      ])
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter("© Auto-Partner")

    if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send(specifyembed)
```

Error:

```
(node:7920) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
```

So if anyone got any solutions on how to fix this please help me out.

Comment: Will you please share the rest of your code (removing the token, of course)? I don't think your error is occurring in this code block, and I don't know what the variable "client" is. Thanks!

Comment: Ye i tought same, I was missing a line of code in index.js so i fixed it

Comment: Will you please share *all* of your code? I really don't think the error is in this section. EDIT: make sure to remove the token from the shared code.

Comment: I fixed it dont worry

Comment: @rez Could you add your own solution to the answer section then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was in util.js and command handler, i havent connected util.js with command handler, depends on what your issue is hopefully this one helps, i know it can depend.